# testing IAP on iPhone

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I tried to establish my IAP in iTunes Connect for the update in my app, but it shows up as "Waiting for Review" and says that it must be submitted with the app. I have had initialization problems with the IAP and so I assume there is a verification issue between my IAP and iTunes Connect. Is it possible to test an IAP without having the IAP submitted? If not I do not think it would be possible at all to test the IAP functionality.

Comment: What is the initialisation problem that you've had?

Comment: BuyProductID FAIL. Not initialized.
Purchaser:BuyProductID(String)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList:Invoke(Object[])
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to test your In App Purchase before submitting it. Like *guidev* mentioned, make sure you create a test account in iTunesConnect; if you need help with this there's some good information in Apple's doc on [Testing In-App Purchase Products](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html).

Once you've got your test account set up and the IAP created in iTunesConnect (sounds like you've already done this), you'll be able to test it fully.

For example, I've got some code like this in one of my projects:

```
#pragma mark - SKProductsRequestDelegate

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest*)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse*)response
{
    NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");
    _productsRequest = nil;

    NSArray* skProducts = response.products;
    for (SKProduct* skProduct in skProducts)
    {
        NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
              skProduct.productIdentifier,
              skProduct.localizedTitle,
              skProduct.price.floatValue);
    }

    _completionHandler(YES, skProducts);
    _completionHandler = nil;
}
```

...you'll get all of the product information that you've set up in iTunesConnect.

Apple's In App Purchase test environment allows you to simulate buying the IAP, restoring the purchase, etc. You don't need to do anything special to use the test environment, it happens automatically when running your app from Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely test In App Purchases before having to submit them.

Just make sure to use a test account (you can create one in iTunes Connect).